How should a sidebar behave when using top and bottom sticky elements?
I'm designing a complex software interface which has a sticky-top element that contains tabs, and a sticky-bottom element with some CTAs. I'm adding a sidebar and I wonder if it should be placed over the bottom-sticky bar or "behind" it. Here are some wireframes to better explain my question:

or


Interesting choices to make.
I see that

If the use cases are such that sticky bottom contains some action items that are specific to instances that appear on the content area (assuming it is the blank space shown in your images), then second option is optimal.
If the sticky bottom is universal, i.e it is going to contain common action items through out your application, then the first option holds good.

In general going with second option is going to give you flexibility/control for you on bottom sticky bar.
Also, do make a retrospection of your hierarchy of actions and pages/screens in your Information Architecture.

In my experience I had a similar situation and we solved that issue depending on the situation of the task. For example, your option A we used it only for those sites were we had a menu bar that had the ability to hide.
For your option B, I used it in an environment where my left side panel was a form to change variables that affected the information in the main area. And the sticky section on the bottom was part of the process that the user was completing at that moment.
So, I'm gonna say that it depends on the context. After our UXR we understood that for our app, the users understood that (in your option B) the left side panel has a higher priority (explication on the image below).

